# Calling windows functions in ASM (push/pop question)

Tags: assembly

I want to call the Sleep function on ASM. So I wrote the following:

```
push 5000
call Sleep
```

Although everything went fine, I had the idea that everytime I pushed a value on the stack, I should also pop it(otherwise it'd get all cluttered later in the program?). Should I pop it? How should I do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Virtually all Win32 API functions use the [`__stdcall`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zxk0tw93(VS.71).aspx) calling convention, where the *called function* is responsible for popping the argument(s) off the stack. So in the case of `Sleep()`, you don't have to do anything else than what you've shown.