# Time Related Interrupts Don't Work in Assembly, in Windows?

Tags: windows, assembly, dos, machine-code

I wanted to create a small program in Assembly language, that delays for several seconds.

I am using Windows XP SP3, and opened a DOS window, and ran **debug.exe**

I entered there this short Assembly program:

> MOV CX,3D
>
> MOV DX,0900
>
> MOV AH,86
>
> INT 15

Function 86h in Interrupt 15h, performs a delay,
and the Duration for the delay is in CX,DX, in MicroSeconds.

So If for example I want to delay for 4 seconds, then it's 4,000,000microseconds = 3D0900h,
and that's what I put in CX,DX.

Running this short program, unfortunately does not perform any delay,
it exits immediately.

I then tried another interrupt function:

Function number 0, in Interrupt 1Ah, returns the PC's clock count, to CX,DX.
Each tick is 1/18.2 seconds.

I then entered and ran this short program:

> MOV AH,0
>
> INT 1A

But unfortunately, CX and DX both equal 0000h after running it.

Is there a reason why 2 Time related interrupts don't work in Windows?
It seems that other interrupts do work..

Is there anything I can do to make them work, so I can achieve the small delay program that I want to write?

Thank you

Comment: You can't call BIOS functions (SW interrupts) in protected mode. If you run a DOS emulator (such as DOSbox), they might work there.

Comment: Thank you Lurker. So maybe is there another way I can perform a Delay in Assembly? I am flexible regarding how I achieve it, as long as I achieve a delay, and as long as it can be the same delay on different machines (which can vary in speed, so simply looping on a NOP command for 1,000,000 times will not be an identical delay..)

Comment: @lurker: This is only half of the truth. Up to Windows Vista, 32-bit-versions, Windows could run DOS programs in "virtual 8086 mode". As far as I know the original BIOS of the PC was used in this case so an "INT" instruction called the original BIOS function of the PC. I/O access as well as hardware interrupts however are always emulated by the OS in "virtual 8086 mode".

Comment: @MartinRosenau interesting. I know the uP has a virtual 8086 mode, but I wasn't aware that Windows had one as well. But sounds like this is N/A for Windows 7 and up.

Comment: Omer, you could look up the Windows API call for delay and call that. There's a wealth of online info about interfacing from Assembly to the Windows API.

Comment: Calling Windows API from Assembly(or more accurate from Machine Code since I am using debug.exe to directly write the code) sounds scary :).. Maybe I should leave the idea? There's no other way via some interrupt?

Comment: Before you call it too scary to do, check it out. You can probably call the API functions you need [directly](http://cs.lmu.edu/~ray/notes/x86assembly/).

Comment: Thank you lurker. I see it. I will not take this path.. If there is a way to do it via some interrupt, then I will gladly adopt it. If not, then I will simply do it in one of the many other programming languages that I can use.. I thought to use assembly language after not using it for so many years.. Sad to see that things changed in a way that makes it less useful..

Comment: Is it sad that things have changed? Do you expect every advance to be backward compatible? The documentation I have for `int 15h ah=86h` says *"It is not intended for use by application programs."*. Please refer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1391689/calling-windows-functions-in-asm-push-pop-question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Omer, there's an excellent solution to your delaying problem that I found on CodeReview.
It uses the BIOS timer tick variable at address 0040h:006Ch directly rather than asking it's value through function 00h on int 1Ah.

Please take a look at 
https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/101035/a-low-tech-approach-to-measuring-game-speed