# Random number generator crashing in assembly

Tags: winapi, assembly, x86, masm, msvcrt

Found this code here on stackoverflow, I understood how it works and tried implementing it. It crashes at the INT 1AH instruction and I don't know why.
When I run it in ollydbg, it stops at the same line.

I also tried the random number generator function rand(void) but it always gives me the same numbers whenever I rerun the code. (different 3 numbers if I call it 3 times in a row, but still the same ones with every rerun)

```
.386
.model flat, stdcall

includelib msvcrt.lib
extern exit: proc
extern printf: proc
extern rand: proc

public start


.data
decimal_format DB "%d",0ah

.code
start:
    mov ah, 00h
    int 1ah

    mov ax,dx
    mov dx,0
    mov cx,10
    div cx

    mov ah,2h
    int 21h

    push edx
    push offset decimal_format
    call printf
    add esp,8

    push 0
    call exit
end start
```

Comment: When you tried `rand` did you first seed the generator using `srand`? Are you running in a DOS emulator?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Time Related Interrupts Don't Work in Assembly, in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29037461/time-related-interrupts-dont-work-in-assembly-in-windows)

Comment: I don't think so... I've seen other codes with the "seed" thing in them but I could undersand what it did, why or how to use/implement it.

Comment: The olden BIOS interrupts (like int 1Ah) can only work in 16-bit real-mode code.  Which does not have a .flat memory model.  So you are surely building this as a 32-bit program, that's instant death when you use int.

Comment: You call the seeder `srand` once before you call `rand` successive times to generate random numbers. Check the documentation for `rand`.

Comment: I agree with Hans and Lurker, although I am confused with the tags. Clearly you are mixing 32-bit Windows code and DOS code and that will fail. However you have used the `[x86-16]` tag which suggests you are trying to create a 16-bit program. So I will ask this. Are you trying to develop a 16-bit DOS application that can run on something like MSDOS or are you trying to create a 32-bit Win32 application? You mention Ollydbg which suggests Windows Application. Is the `[x86-16]` tag a mistake?

Comment: Introductory CS classes really should not be teaching how to write assembly-language MS-DOS programs. It does nothing to prepare students for any real-world uses of assembly (like vectorizing a critical loop or writing a device driver), it doesn’t look anything like an `asm` procedure in a modern program or prepare students in any way to write one, it’s useless for any practical purpose and it’s not even simpler than modern ISAs.

Comment: I know that professors my age or a little younger probably learned 16-bit assembly themselves, back in the ’80s or ’90s, but seriously, modern compilers and assemblers are free.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are writing Win32 programs you can't call BIOS and DOS services like `Int 1ah`, `Int 10h`, `Int 21h` etc. That will crash your application as Win32 programs do not have access to those services.

The basic `rand` and `srand` in the Windows *C* library (MSVCRT.LIB) are based on a linear congruent generator (LCG) pseudo-random number generator (PRNG). This formula relies on a seed value to set the initial state of the PRNG. The initial state when your program executes will always be the same each time the program is restarted. Every call to `rand` will then reproduce a pseudo-random number, but the numbers will be the same sequence each time the program is run.

[`srand`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/srand?view=vs-2019) can be used to change the seed value of the PRNG. Changing the seed value will alter the numbers `rand` will produce but they will always be the same sequence of numbers given the same seed. What you need is a mechanism to set the seed value to a different value each time the program is run. You can use the *C* library [`time`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/time-time32-time64?view=vs-2019) function with a NULL(0) parameter to get the number of seconds since midnight January 1, 1970. This value should be different as long as your program isn't run quickly in such a way it executes within the same second. This is generally good enough.

You can then pass the value returned by `time(0)` in EAX to `srand` to set the seed value. Only call `srand` once when your program starts. From that point on you should be able to call [`rand`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/rand?view=vs-2019) to get a new random number. `rand` returns value between 0 and RAND_MAX and RAND_MAX is 32767.

This sample code does `srand(time(0))` to initialize the seed and then loops 10 times printing out a different random number retrieved by calls to `rand`. Each time you run the program the output should be different.

```
.386
.model flat, C

includelib msvcrt.lib
extern exit: proc
extern printf: proc
extern rand: proc
extern srand: proc
extern time: proc

.data
decimal_format DB "%d", 0ah, 0 
                             ; Ensure string is NUL(0) terminated

.code

main PROC
    push ebx                 ; Save callee saved (non-volatile) registers that we use.
                             ; EBX, EBP, ESI, EDI, ESP are non-volatile. For each
                             ; one we clobber we must save it and restore it before
                             ; returning from `main`

    push 0
    call time                ; EAX=time(0)
    add esp, 4
    push eax                 ; Use time as seed
    call srand               ; srand(time(0))
    add esp, 4

    mov ebx, 10              ; Loop 10 times

loopit:
    call rand                ; Get a random number between 0 and 32767 into EAX

    push eax
    push offset decimal_format
    call printf              ; Print the random number
    add esp,8

    dec ebx
    jnz loopit               ; Loop until the counter EBX reaches 0

    pop ebx                  ; Restore callee saved registers
    xor eax, eax             ; Return 0 from our program
    ret
main ENDP

END
```

Some other important changes. I use the *C* (CDECL) calling convention (via `.model flat, C`) which automatically handles decorating `main PROC` with an underscore in 32-bit code. I have also changed `start` to `main` and changed `end start` to just `end`. We don't want to use `end main` either because that directive will make `main` the entry point to our code and will skip the *C* runtime initialization that usually has to be done prior to `main` being called. Failure to have the *C* runtime initialization called may make *C* library function work unexpectedly or crash altogether.

When the code finishes I do a `ret` to return to the *C* startup code which will exit for us. The code also preserves the non-volatile (callee saved) registers. See the Microsoft [32-bit CDECL calling convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#cdecl) for more information.